# Do/While to check for Null in textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, null

For an assignment I need to build a WPF C# Form that checks to make sure something has been enter in the textbox named txtCityInput and textbox name txtStateInput.

I tried this do/while but it creates and infinite loop (on the MessageBox).

```
    private void txtCityInput_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        do
        {
            txtCityInput.Focus();
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a City");
        }

        while (txtCityInput.Text.Length == 0);
    }
```

Again it I have to use either a Do Statement or Do/While statement to check that the user has entered "something" into these textboxes.

Comment: Does the user ever get chance to type in something in the textbox? Or the only thing he sees is a message box?

Comment: err, why do you want a loop at all? This event is triggered when the textbox lost focus, so every time.

Comment: Is it part of the assignment that you have to use a `do`/`while`?  If so, is it part of the assignment that you use WPF, or was it intended to maybe use a console app?

Comment: yes focus is set to the first textbox (txtCityInput) when the app runs. When they try to leave the txtCityInput textbox the do/while runs on the leave event for that control.

Comment: ah yes. the coworkers of tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way of using do-while loop for that situation is adding an extra if condition.

```
private void txtCityInput_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    do
    {
        if (txtCityInput.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            txtCityInput.Focus();
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a City");
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    while (!txtCityInput.Focused); 
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, but if you see, there is no looping ;-)

Comment: Orkun actually this solution works the first time, but after inputting something it throws up the messagebox.

Comment: the edited answer worked like a charm .. thanks Orkun. appreciate your time and attention.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do:

```
private void txtCityInput_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtCityInput.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        txtCityInput.Focus();
        MessageBox.Show("Enter a City");
    }
}
```

The event should be triggered again each time he leaves the textbox.

Comment: Dan that solution works, but the instructor definitely wants to me use either a "Do Loop" or "Do/While Loop).

Comment: @NateE. it is not possible, you are actually blocking the user to Key-in (by having  loop).

Comment: maybe i'm misreading the instructions then, I tried to get clarification from him but due to lack of a response I was trying to do it that way. On my first build I used the method you describe above and it works well.

Comment: @NateE. than put break; after calling MessageBox.Show

Comment: @OrkunBekar - That would defeat the whole purpose of do-while.

Comment: @NateE. - You could update your question with the exact instructions you received, maybe we would figure something up that you missed.